# React Hooks: How to pass the prop setState, while using the same setState itslef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I have a react app that has 50+ of components. Among them there are few components that share a common state.

Everything was running smooth until I got to the Modal component, which contains 5 other components (which are like tabs, each with their own component and content) which share the same state value, so I pass them as props, each component at a time. I have noticed this is very inefficient as I can see a visual lag (In my Modal component) , which is not there in the other components.

My question here is what is the correct way to import or pass my state to the child components, someone suggested me to use context, but It is not suitable for my application.

Below is my code, I apologize I cannot reproduce this error on a sandbox because the application is too large.

Parent component (the main page that user sees, when he clicks the add button, I take the relevant props and send it to the modal component, which then takes that state and shares it across it's five other child components (tabs))

**Main Page**
In this function record is the prop that I am sending to the modal

```
   function MainPage = () => { 
    return <Modal record={record} />
    }
```

**ModalComponent**

```
 function modal({record}){ // destructing the props here
    return(
      <TabPane
                tab={
                  <span>
                    <InfoCircleOutlined style={{ fontSize: 14 }} />
                    Tab1
                  </span>
                }
                key="1"
              >
                  <component1 formProp={form} record={record} />
                
              </TabPane>
     <TabPane
                tab={
                  <span>
                    <InfoCircleOutlined style={{ fontSize: 14 }} />
                    Tab1
                  </span>
                }
                key="1"
              >
                  <component2 formProp={form} record={record} />
                
              </TabPane>
    )
}
```

Likewise, I have three other components inside my modal component, each component needs that same record prop to render their own content.

What I am doing wrong here and what is causing the lag? Again, I apologize the code snippets are not detailed enough, please let me know if you need anything clarified.

UPDATE:

After taking the suggestions and looking, I think this is what's causing the lag.

so this is my modal component:

**step 1**

```
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState({
    title: '',
    content: '',
    visible: false,
  })
```

and it gets triggered via this onClick prop of a button,

**Step 2**

```
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                setModalContent({
                  title: 'Edit Pay Item',
                  content: <Test record={record} modal={setModalContent} 
                  visible: true,
                })
              }}
            />
```

**Step 3: here"s where my modal lags.**

So I reuse the same modal component and it never lags, but in this specific there is a problem.

If you see this line below, I am passing setModalContent itself as a prop, While I am using it. Maybe this is the reason why It is lagging. So what would be a better way to implement this logic? I need to pass the setModalContent while using the setState (which is setModalContent) itself.

setModalContent({
title: 'Edit Pay Item',
content: <Test record={record} modal={setModalContent}
visible: true,
})

Comment: I don't see anything in what you've shared that would cause a delay in rendering. Passing a prop to multiple children is a common thing to do and i can't think how it would be related to what you're seeing. Context is useful when you don't know how far you need to pass the prop, or don't know which components need the prop, but none of that seems to be the case for you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of passing state would require analysis of your code structure, state management approach and how components are being organised/used.
But as you are passing record inside modal, and based on assumption that you would be fetching a list of records inside your app and each one can be passed inside modal to load it up, the lag may not be directly due to this modal/component structure

For lagging of the modal, you can look into your code for following points

1. Is there any big image/images being loaded inside modal without being properly compressed as a big byte volume in UI can cause lagging
2. Are you opening your modal at the same time when you are doing an expensive state update that affects a lot of components and leaves minimal resources of UI thread for other tasks
3. Are you doing any expensive calculations while opening modal that consumes computational resources
4. Have you tried commenting your modal's components step by step to narrow down a specific component/number of components that starts generating visual lag

If you look your code while keeping above points in perspective, you would be able to narrow down actual cause

Comment: Thank you Abu this is very helpful. And yes you are correct I am fetching a list of records on two of the 4 child components.

Comment: You are welcome. 
Just look at the app from the perspective of resource consumptions. What else is happening inside the app at the moment when you are experiencing lag and you would narrow down the issue

Comment: There are no Images or any heavy files, but there are many state changes when the modal is open or closed, you were right on with the second point. So what would a good approach now might be to handle expensive state update that affects a lot of components.

Comment: Load the modal and once modal is visible and transition of loading modal is complete then do a react state update. You can look at the React component life cycle and utilise React hooks that runs after render cycles

Comment: sure I will try it out and I will keep updating this post with more relevant content. thanks!