# React and Ant design: Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

**Full Error**

[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

**This Question is an extension to my other question, I will post the link below**

[React Hooks: How to pass the prop setState, while using the same setState itslef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762235/react-hooks-how-to-pass-the-prop-setstate-while-using-the-same-setstate-itslef/69762606#69762606)

**Issue**

I have a complex react app and use ant design. All the components were running smooth except for this one, There is an Ant Design Modal which has Ant Design Tabs inside it, each Tab is it's own component and some tabs have a useEffect, which fetch the data and display in a list.
So my modal never lagged anywhere in the application except this page, and I get that violation error and I am not sure how to debug or fix it. I am not using any event handlers, maybe ant design is using it but I have not changed any.